# Properties in Maven

Tags: maven

I would like to create a property of this kind :

```
<properties> 
  <ignoredpackage>
     <ignore>com.example.*</ignore>
     <ignore>com.another.example.*</ignore> 
  </ignoredpackage>
<properties>
```

So that I can use it in my pom like that :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <instrumentation>
        <ignores>
          ${ignoredpackage}
        </ignores>
        <excludes>
        ...
```

But this doesn't work, is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this.

The `<properties/>` tag only works like this:

```
<properties>
    <foo>bar</foo>
    <blah>dotfoo</blah>
</properties>
```